# How do I rename parent field name and nested field value in mongodb using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have following document:

```
{

   "dataset_path":"path_of_dataset",

   "project_1":{

      "model_1":"path_of_model_1",

      "model_2":"path_of_model_2"

   }

}
```

I want to change **"project_1"** to **"renamed_project_1"** and **"path_of_model_1"** to **"new_model_1_path"**. The resultant output should be as follows:

```
{

   "dataset_path":"path_of_dataset",

   "renamed_project_1":{

      "renamed_model_1":"new_model_1_path",

      "model_2":"path_of_model_2"

   }

}
```

Here is what I tried:

```
db.collection.update_many({'dataset_path': 'path_to_dataset'}, {'$rename': {"project_1": "renamed_project_1"}},
                          {'$set': {"project_1.model_1": "new_model_1_path"}})
```

but the above query throws following error:

> pymongo.errors.WriteError: Updating the path X would create a conflict
> at X.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're trying to mutate `project_1` field two times in a single query. Mongo just doesn't know how to deal with that.
You should consider splitting two operations:

```py
db.collection.update_many({'dataset_path': 'path_to_dataset'}, {'$rename': {"project_1": "renamed_project_1"}})
db.collection.update_many({'dataset_path': 'path_to_dataset'}, {'$set': {"renamed_project_1.model_1": "new_model_1_path"}})
```

Comment: As an addition, I don't believe it is possible using a single query. That sounds weird to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.update_many({}, {"$rename": {"old_value": "new_value"}})
```